# Is There a Field for the Overlap of Geometry and Physics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, geometry, aerodynamics

What I mean is how the shape of an object affects it's physical properties.

I've been studying Marine Biology and there's constant talk of how a fish's shape determines how well it can swim but no explanation of why, say, "Stream lining" reduces water resistance outside of it "just making sense" and I'd like something more in-depth.

Similar phenomena would be: How a blade's shape determines how it cuts, Why certain shapes are more structurally sound, What determines a shape's aerodynamics.

Is there a field of research dealing with this? It's been driving me mad.

Comment: That would be called "fluid dynamics".

Comment: You might ask this on a biology forum.  I know of one biologist who thought about things like this.

Comment: A classic work on this topic is *On Growth and Form* by the Scottish mathematical biologist D'Arcy Wentworth Thompson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Growth_and_Form Unfortunately, Thompson was sceptical of natural selection, but it's still an excellent book, filled with beautiful illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

The question of how form affects function is too broad to constitute a specialization in its own right. Depending on what's actually happening with the object and the task or function it is performing, the importance of its physical geometry to the task in question could be anything from absolutely critical to completely irrelevant.

In fluid dynamics, one learns how and why streamlining typically reduces fluid drag. The soundness of structures like bridges and buildings follows from how the building materials respond to stress and strain, and is studied in great detail by mechanical and structural engineers (it tends to be a bit too much on the applied side for most physics programs). If you have specific questions about how the shape of $X$ influences $Y$, then this is a good place to ask.